# Gauss seidel Implementation in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, numerical-methods

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import solve_triangular as triSolve

#O(n) per iteration, so overall O(nN), good for large SPD/SDD matrices
def GS_iter(A, b, N):
    m = len(A)
    L = np.tril(A)
    P = L-A
    print(P)
    
    x = np.zeros(m)
    print(x)
    for k in range(N):
        x = triSolve(L,b+P@x, True)
        
    return x
        


#examples
A = np.array([[10,2,3,1],[1,10,0,1],[0.2,1,10,2],[0.1,3,3,10]])
b = np.array([1,2,1,0])

x = GS_iter(A,b,50000)

ans = A@x-b
print(ans)
print(np.linalg.norm(ans))
```

Above is my Gauss-Seidel method in Python. For some reason it is not converging even after 50000 iterations to the solution even when the matrix A is strict diagonal dominant. Below is the same implementation in MATLAB which works:

```
function x = gSeidel(A,B,N)
    [n,~] = size(A);
    L = tril(A);
    P = L-A; %P = -U
    
    x = zeros(n,1); %x_0
    for k = 1:N
        x = L\(B+P*x);
    end
end
```

What mistakes did I make? I think it is in TriSolve method since if I replaced it with regular LU solver such as (np.linalg.solve) it works. Why doesn't triangular solve behave as intended here?

Answer (score 2):

the lower argument is the fourth
replace your line by `x = triSolve(L,b+P@x, lower=True)`

```
Signature:
triSolve(
    a,
    b,
    trans=0,
    lower=False,
    unit_diagonal=False,
    overwrite_b=False,
    debug=None,
    check_finite=True,
)
```